# Google OAuth2 not working

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

My android app needs to access a Web client. So I am using

```
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accountName, scopes);
```

to get the token, where `scope` is the `Client ID` of type `Web application`. This approach works fine with an app that I inherited. The same server needs to talk to a different app. So I am using the same approach. But I keep getting

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil$1.zzam(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil$1.zzan(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.zza(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

So the only thing I can think of is that I need to register the package name of the new app with the google developer console `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/`. Is that accurate? The scope is of the form `audience:server:client_id:projectid-somestring.apps.googleusercontent.com`. Otherwise, is there a place that I should register the secret with the android app?

Comment: Also might this have anything to do with my `google-services.json` file? That file has its own `auth_client` section specific to my app.